# Java Counting Words and Characters

Tags: java, string, text-files

I'm supposed to create a program that counts the number of words and the average number of characters(without spaces) from a text file.  I've created the program I'm just having one problem. My total number of characters counters counts the characters "-" and "." when counting words, I don't want this to happen. Currently I'm getting 300 characters counted. There are four "." and one "-" that should be removed from the counter so I can get the total value of 295. I tried using char but I get stuck with errors that don't allow me to compare string to char.  My friend recommended I compare I should try to incorporate a way to compare char to Unicode but I don't know how to begin to code that.

```
public class Count {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File sFile = new File("s.txt"); 
    FileReader in;                          
    BufferedReader readFile;            
    String sourceCode;
    int amountOfWords = 0;
    int amountOfChars = 0;

    try {
        in = new FileReader(sFile); 
        readFile = new BufferedReader(in);      
        while ((sourceCode = readFile.readLine()) != null)  {
            String[] words = sourceCode.split(" ");
            amountOfWords = amountOfWords + words.length;
            for (String word : words) {
                amountOfChars = amountOfChars + word.length();
            }
    }
            System.out.println("Amount of Chars is " + amountOfChars);
            System.out.println("Amount of Words is " + (amountOfWords + 1));
            System.out.println("Average Word Length is "+ (amountOfChars/amountOfWords));
    readFile.close();                                       
    in.close();                                             
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File does not exist or could not be found.");
    System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
        System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code currently *includes* "-" and "." in words because they are not removed by the split. **Accepting this baseline**, what can be done with the *existing* "each character in a 'word'" loop to only count/include the 'letters'? Why might an exclusion-filter still prove problematic for "," or "@"? How can [Character.isLetter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) (or a similar method) be useful for an inclusion-filter?

Comment: You can also checkout the `Character` class. Take a look at `Character.isAlphabetic(int)`.

Comment: You can call split with regular expressions. Do you know these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing

```
String[] words = sourceCode.split(" ");
```

get rid of all the chars you do not want using `replace`

e.g.

```
sourceCode = sourceCode.replace ("-", "").replace (".", "");
String[] words = sourceCode.split(" ");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use all 3 characters "","." and ";" in the spilt I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to your question...

```
public static int numberOfWords(File someFile) {
    int num=0;
    try {
        String line=null;
        FileReader filereader=new FileReader(someFile);
        try (BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(filereader)) {
            while((line=bf.readLine()) !=null) {
                if (!line.equals("\n")) {
                    if (line.contains(" ") {
                        String[] l=line.split(" ");
                        num=num+l.length;
                    } else {
                        num++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    return num;
}

public static int numberOfChars(File someFile) {
    int num=0;
    try {
        String line=null;
        FileReader filereader=new FileReader(someFile);
        try (BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(filereader)) {
            while((line=bf.readLine()) !=null) {
                if (!line.equals("\n")) {
                    if (line.contains(" ") {
                        String[] l=line.split(" ");
                        for (String s : l) {
                            s=replaceAllString(s, "-", "");
                            s=replaceAllString(s, ".", "");
                            String[] sp=s.split("");
                            num=num+sp.length;
                        }
                    } else {
                        line=replaceAllString(line, "-", "");
                        line=replaceAllString(line, ".", "");
                        String[] sp=line.split("");
                        num=num+sp.length;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    return num;
}

public static String replaceAllString(String s, String c, String d){
    String temp = s.replace(c ,d);
    return temp;
}
```